# Is a `requirejs-config.js` needed to include a JavaScript file?

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

Many answers here on StackExchange and in documentation around the Internet indicate that to include a custom JavaScript file in a Magento 2 store that you should create a `requirejs-config.js` to specify a file alias that you will then separately reference to require it.

For example, you might have this `requirejs-config.js` file:

```js
var config = {
   map: {
       '*': {
           myscript: 'My_Module/js/myscript',
       }
   }
};
```

And this in your PHTML:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['myscript'], function($) {
        // optional loaded callback here
    });
</script>
```

This works, but the question is:

**Are both steps really necessary to include the JavaScript file?**

Comment: @St3phan There are a whole lot of questions on here that are basically dups asking how to add JS. That's not the point of this question: it's a self-answered rhetorical question documenting that the `requirejs-config.js` isn't really needed in case others wonder that in the future. If you have the access (I don't), please remove that duplicate question suggestion from this.

Comment: Your answer is identical, even less information than in the duplicate response.

Comment: @St3phan, the point here is to be direct about the question of whether `requirejs-config.php` is needed. Your answer on the other question implies it is needed, when it's not.

Comment: It is explained both solutions.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

The `require-config.js` isn't needed. All it's doing is creating a simpler alias, so most of the time it's not worth it if your JavaScript file isn't a library that's going to be required by a lot of other code. You can just include the path to the file you're requiring directly in your call to RequireJs:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['My_Module/js/myscript'], function($) {
        // optional loaded callback here
    });
</script>
```